# Bentching in a different place than where you started eating

Tags: halacha, bentching

If you ate a meal by the table and finished it on the couch (in the same living room), can you bentch by the couch or must you go back to the table to bentch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 184:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=173)

One can Bench in a new location so long as he ate there, and is still satisfied from the first eating.

Comment: Does drinking count as eating? Also are there any conditions on where the new location must be?